# addColumn to Admin Udropship with commission_percent not work

Tags: php, magento

i want to add a Column in Admin of Udropship Module in Vendors Views.

In the module i find the file:

app/community/Unirgy/Dropship/Block/Adminhtml/Vendor/Grid.php and i write this line:

```
$this->addColumn('commission_percent', array(
        'header'    => $hlp->__('Commission Percent'),
        'index'     => 'commission_percent',
));
```

after

```
$this->addColumn('email', array(
        'header'    => $hlp->__('Email'),
        'index'     => 'email',
));
```

but i not see a new column in admin, why ?

It's because i don't have "commission_percent" in Collection ?

I see in DB that "commission_percent" is in the udropship/vendor table inside a row "custom_vars_combined" in an array.

Answer (score 0):

So when you add columns to grids you also need to add the column to the select.

Simply update the function that prepares the collection and add the following call.

```
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('your_attribute');
```